# My Dell laptop running Ubuntu Linux 11.10 hangs on reboot but not shutdown. How do I diagnose this?

Tags: linux, logging, shutdown, reboot, ubuntu-11.10

My Dell laptop running Ubuntu Linux 11.10 hangs reliably while shutting down for a reboot, but when I shutdown, it will complete successfully.  How do I diagnose this?  I don't know what log files I should go to in order to observe the relevant system events during the time of reboot/shutdown.

shutdown -r now; # This results in a hang during the Ubuntu shutdown splash.

shutdown -hP now; # This will work perfectly and quickly.

Comment: You can start by [disabling the splash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen) and posting what messages the kernel outputs when rebooting.